# Django sitemap.xml throwing Server Error (500) in production

Tags: django, django-2.1

My app is throwing ERROR 500 while accessing example.com/sitemap.xml
Additional server configurations = Nginx+Gunicorn+postgres

Here are my files

```
sitemap.py

from django.contrib.sitemaps import Sitemap
from .models import Post, Status 

class PostSitemap(Sitemap):    
    changefreq = 'daily'
    priority = 0.9

    def items(self):
        return Post.objects.filter(status=0)

    def lastmod(self, obj):
        return obj.created_on

class StatusSitemap(Sitemap):
    changefreq='daily'
    priority = 0.9

    def item(self):
        return Status.objects.filter(status=0)

    def lastmod(self, obj):
```

url.py

```
sitemaps = {
    'posts': PostSitemap,
    'status': StatusSitemap
}
urlpatterns = [ path('sitemap.xml/', sitemap, {'sitemaps': sitemaps},
 name='sitemaps'),]
```

Don't know why is this showing error 500

**UPDATE** 
Tarckbacks - 
[image]

Comment: Show us the full traceback for the error. If you haven't configured django to log the error to a file, do that first. You should always have an error log on your production machine.

Comment: Currently, the site is live, I noticed one thing in my local computer when the debug = False it's generating the site map, but when Debug is True it throws ERROR 500

Comment: It doesn't matter that the site is live, you should still log your errors to disk (or use a service like Sentry) so you can view them. There's always going to be situations where something happens on a live site that you didn't plan for (because live data is different than local data) and then you'll want to have a trace of the error. Otherwise there's no way to debug.

Comment: First of all thanks a ton for that awesome suggestion okay I got this error ` raise TemplateDoesNotExist(template_name, chain=chain)` How to resolve it?

Comment: can you post the full trace here? (not in a comment but in your question, otherwise it'll be impossible to read)

Comment: Done kindly have a look

Comment: Sorry that's not the stack trace, it's the view of the line of code that raises the error. a stack trace has the full call stack (showing which method called the `get_template()` method in the first place, and which method called that one, etc...). Also the error should show the template name that doesn't exist.

Comment: Can you for completeness show the relevant imports in *urls.py*? What is `sitemap` exactly? Is it imported directly from `django.contrib.sitemaps.views`?

Comment: Yes it is imported directly from views, `from django.contrib.sitemaps.views import sitemap`

Comment: still, please look better at your logs and find the full error trace. It will tell you which template does not exist and clarify the issue.

Comment: by the way, your URL path is `sitemap.xml/` with the slash, so fetching `example.com/sitemap.xml` should throw a 404 error.

Comment: Damn it is saying sitemap.xml doesn't exist! Sitemaps.py should generate one automatically right?

Comment: have you added 'django.contrib.sitemaps' to your `INSTALLED_APPS` in settings? otherwise it won't find the templates directory inside `sitemaps`

Comment: Damn please don't kill me for this, I thought it comes preinstalled, I am extremely sorry and thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay In case someone was dumb enough to repeat this silly mistake like me!

Dear, you have forgotten to add `'django.contrib.sitemaps'`, in you INSTALLED APPS.